# Infinite SVG animation smoothly retrieve initial state on hover

Tags: css, animation, svg, hover, css-transitions

I would like my infinite svg animation to pause on its initial or final state when I hover it. I tried with JS to remove the class or in CSS to set `animation-iteration-count: unset;` on hover or set `animation: none;` but in each case, the transition is abrupt. I would like it smooth. Here is the code :
HTML

```
    <div class="button">
        <svg version="1.1" id="sound--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"   >
          <rect class="rect-1 rect-anim" x="10" fill="currentColor"></rect>
          <rect class="rect-2 rect-anim" x="30" fill="currentColor"></rect>
          <rect class="rect-3 rect-anim" x="50" fill="currentColor"></rect> 
          <rect class="rect-4 rect-anim" x="70" fill="currentColor"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#sound--icon .rect-anim{
    animation-name: sound-icon-anim;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.97,0,0,1);
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/*  #sound--icon:hover .rect-anim{
    animation-iteration-count: unset;
} 
 */

#sound--icon .rect-1{
    animation-delay: .1s;
}

#sound--icon .rect-2{
    animation-delay: .3s;
}

#sound--icon .rect-3{
    animation-delay: .5s;
}

#sound--icon .rect-4{
    animation-delay: .7s;
}

@keyframes sound-icon-anim{
    0%{
        height: 30%;
    }
    10%{
        height: 70%;
    }
    20%{
        height: 50%;
    }
    50%{
        height: 80%;
    }
    60%{
        height: 100%;
    }
    70%{
        height: 70%;
    }
    100%{
        height: 30%;
    }
}
```

What I'm aiming to do eventually is :

- animation is running
- heights smoothly go to 50% when div is hovered / animation is paused
- heights smoothly go to 30% when div is clicked / animation is paused
- heights smoothly go to 50% when div is hovered again / animation is still paused
- animation re-runs when div is clicked again (hence from 50% and not from 30% as the 0% animation state states)

Does this seems possible to you in pure CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this in pure CSS. With the [Web Animations API](https://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1), it is possible, but at the current state of implementation, only part of the way is realistic.

What you can achieve is stopping the animation at the end of an iteration cycle. Stopping at a point that is *not* the end of a cycle would need the [AnimationTimeline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationTimeline) to be implemented. But it is currently missing for Chrome.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(button => {
    //.getAnimations() returns an array
    const animations = [...button.querySelectorAll('.rect-anim')]
        .map(r => r.getAnimations())
        .flat();

    button.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        for (let animation of animations) {
            const iterations = animation.effect.getComputedTiming()
                .currentIteration + 1;
            animation.effect.updateTiming({iterations})
        }
    });

    button.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        for (let animation of animations) {
            animation.effect.updateTiming({iterations: Infinity});
        }
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

#sound--icon .rect-anim{
    animation-name: sound-icon-anim;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.97,0,0,1);
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#sound--icon .rect-1{
    animation-delay: .1s;
}

#sound--icon .rect-2{
    animation-delay: .3s;
}

#sound--icon .rect-3{
    animation-delay: .5s;
}

#sound--icon .rect-4{
    animation-delay: .7s;
}

@keyframes sound-icon-anim{
    0%{
        height: 30%;
    }
    10%{
        height: 70%;
    }
    20%{
        height: 50%;
    }
    50%{
        height: 80%;
    }
    60%{
        height: 100%;
    }
    70%{
        height: 70%;
    }
    100%{
        height: 30%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="this-button" class="button">
    <svg version="1.1" id="sound--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"   >
      <rect class="rect-1 rect-anim" x="10" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor"></rect>
      <rect class="rect-2 rect-anim" x="30" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor"></rect>
      <rect class="rect-3 rect-anim" x="50" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor"></rect> 
      <rect class="rect-4 rect-anim" x="70" y="40" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate, I learned some stuff. Finaly, I've done something pretty satisfying concerning the result in JS. I calculated the height of the rectangle when hovering with `getComputedStyle`, and changed it to what I wanted adding a transition. I think the code can be optimized though, especially `setTimeout` part which remove the CSS class which define the animation. If it's not there it messes with the fourth rectangle.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('#sound__icon')
const btn = document.querySelector('.mute')
const rects = svg.children
let mute = false

function muting(){
    if(!mute){
        mute = true
      for(let rect of rects){
            rect.style.height = '30%'
      }
    }
    else{
        mute = false
        audioAnimActivate()
    }
}

function audioAnimActivate(){
    for(let rect of rects){
        rect.classList.add('rect-anim')
    }
    svg.classList.add('sound__icon--on')
}

function audioAnimFreeze(){
    for(let rect of rects){
        let rectHeight = window.getComputedStyle(rect).height
        rect.style.height = rectHeight
        rect.classList.remove('rect-anim')
        rect.style.transition = 'height .5s ease'
        rect.style.height = '50%'
    }
    //? How to code this better ???
    setTimeout(() => svg.classList.remove('sound__icon--on'), 16)
}

btn.addEventListener('click', muting)
btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    if(mute){
        rects[0].style.height = '60%'
        rects[1].style.height = '20%'
        rects[2].style.height = '40%'
        rects[3].style.height = '80%'
    }
    else{
        audioAnimFreeze()
    }
    
})
btn.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    if(!mute){
        audioAnimActivate()
    }
    else{
        for(let rect of rects){
            rect.style.height = '30%'
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.mute{
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: none;
}

.rect-1, .rect-2, .rect-3, .rect-4{
    width: 10%;
    height: 30%;
}

.sound__icon--on .rect-anim{
    animation-name: sound-icon-anim;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.97,0,0,1);
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.sound__icon--on .rect-1{
    animation-delay: .1s;
}

.sound__icon--on .rect-2{
    animation-delay: .3s;
}

.sound__icon--on .rect-3{
    animation-delay: .5s;
}

.sound__icon--on .rect-4{
    animation-delay: .7s;
}

@keyframes sound-icon-anim{
    0%{
        height: 30%;
    }
    10%{
        height: 70%;
    }
    20%{
        height: 50%;
    }
    50%{
        height: 80%;
    }
    60%{
        height: 100%;
    }
    70%{
        height: 70%;
    }
    100%{
        height: 30%;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="mute">
        <svg version="1.1" id="sound__icon" class="sound__icon--on"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"   >
          <rect class="rect-1 rect-anim" x="15" fill="currentColor"></rect>
          <rect class="rect-2 rect-anim" x="35" fill="currentColor"></rect>
          <rect class="rect-3 rect-anim" x="55" fill="currentColor"></rect> 
          <rect class="rect-4 rect-anim" x="75" fill="currentColor"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
```